# Responsive axis with percentage coordinates

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, graph, charts

In an attempt to build a responsive scatter graph with **d3.js**, I'm using %-based coordinates in a 100% x 100% `svg` element.

How can I `.call(axis)` and get it to layout the axis using `%` and not `px` values, so that they always fit the svg and the plotted data?

Do I need to manually draw the axes in this case? If so how would I get the regular tick values for each axis?

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <g class='data'>
        <circle cx='1%' cy='2%' />
        <circle cx='3%' cy='12%' />
        <circle cx='10%' cy='24%' />
    </g>
    <g class='axis'>
        <!-- is there a way to generate the axis ticks with x=% y=% ? -->
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of your markup? It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do—do you want the SVG element itself to be responsive, i.e. resizing to viewport/layout changes, or the internal SVG components to be responsive?

Comment: @Terry I've added a simplified example of how it currently looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with D3. The axis component will generate an axis that corresponds to the associated range, i.e. to make it any particular size, you have to modify the output range of the associated scale. You can do this quite easily in a responsive manner though by computing the size of the range in relation to the window size and updating the axis when that changes, for example

```
xScale.range([0, window.innerWidth]);
```

Comment: Could you give a quick example of how you'd compute that?

Comment: I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense. So you could potentially do something like `function onResize() { xScale.range([ 0, $('#svg').outerWidth() ]) }`